# Templating and Themeing with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well with my CMS I am building I was able to purchase a really nice admin template from theme forest and I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the themeing/templating.

Login Page Here: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/admintemp/login.html

Control Panel: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/admintemp/index.html

Now most of the files are the same however I'm going to be using the Tank Auth library for my user login and authentication which includes the registration and forgot password form, etc. 
I want to be able to use the same layout, template, theme whatever is the proper term for those authenitcation forms because if you notice on the login page there's a body class of login which complicates things a little.

Or is there a better way to accomplish this without a templating library or even is there a better library that I should use?

Anybody have any ideas?

Newest Code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
}


public function index()
{
    // Set up the template. 
    $this->template->set_layout('default')->enable_parser(false);

    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }


}
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

FIXED THIS ISSUE

Comment: While I would love to help you, I'm not sure myself on what would be deemed the **correct** way. You should probably edit the template you bought and change the HTML and CSS to be more semantic to your needs. Anyhow, this question does not pertain to CI or PHP; it is a pure HTML/CSS semantics question. You should change your tags, and maybe someone following those tags will be able to help you more...

Comment: I think it does because I still have to because I'm still wanting to use this Template Library. At least I believe this is what I need.  http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show

Comment: I apologize my thing is I almost have it finalized. I am trying to figure out how to get my default layout to show up when the controller loads. My code is above with the edit.

Comment: ultimately its going to see if a session exists and if there isn't then its going to go to the login page but I just want to atleast be able to go to my controller and see that the html is loading correctly.

Comment: I updated my code to show what I have now and i'm not sure what I put to have it set up the template and view it when i get to the login page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most basic ways of templating a site in CodeIgniter is to create a template or "layout" php file that dynamically loads another view file.

Try something like this and see if it works for you:

**views/layout.php**

```
<html><body>
<?php $this->load->view('header.php'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($component); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('footer.php'); ?>
</body></html>
```

**views/header.php**

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

**views/footer.php**

```
<h6>Footer</h6>
```

**views/login.php**

```
<p>Login here!</p>
```

**controllers/welcome.php**

```
public function index() {
    $data['component'] = "login";
    $this->load->view("layout", $data);
}
```

Comment: I have a template file similar to that. Could I have an issue with my default template, or header/footer files that is causing the misalignment with the div login-footer?